# Не работают уведомления на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, уведомления

Появился вопрос как сделать уведомление на JavaScript. Прочитал много статей по поводу этого на том же Хабре, *developer.mozilla.org*, но все примеры которые там приводились не работают. Видимо это из-за того что я не использовал `localhost://`. Можно ли как то сделать push уведомления без использования `localhost`, a открывать сайт через `file:///`?

Вот пример кода который я хочу выполнить (взял с сайта itproger.com):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Push уведомления</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="notifSet()" value="Notification">

<script>
    function notifyMe () {
        var notification = new Notification ("Все еще работаешь?", {
            tag : "ache-mail",
            body : "Пора сделать паузу и отдохнуть",
            icon : "https://itproger.com/img/notify.png"
        });
    }

    function notifSet () {
        if (!("Notification" in window)){
            alert ("Ваш браузер не поддерживает уведомления.");
        }
        else if (Notification.permission === "granted"){
            setTimeout(notifyMe, 2000);
        }
        else if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {
            Notification.requestPermission (function (permission) {
                if (!('permission' in Notification))
                Notification.permission = permission;
                if (permission === "granted")
                setTimeout(notifyMe, 2000);
            });
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: это не push, это обычный notification

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Хорошо, буду знать, а вы знаете какое-то решение этой проблемы? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Да, нотификация по идее только для сайта, поэтому нужен сервер